# Error con funcion en firebase

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

tengo el siguiente error el cual sale por pantalla

```
error.ts:166 Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field nombre)
    at new Gr (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:47893)
    at Rd.createError (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:321144)
    at _d.parseScalarValue (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:326742)
    at _d.parseData (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:324639)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:324815
    at Jr (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:48532)
    at _d.parseObject (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:324788)
    at _d.parseData (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:324388)
    at _d.parseSetData (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:322110)
    at Yd.set (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:342729)
```

eh cambiado los nombres y revisado las variables si esta correctas pero aun asi me lanza ese error, lo unico que quiero es guardar, les muestro igual el codigo del JS

```
function Ingresa_Datos(){

    var nom = document.getElementById("name").Value;
    var tel = document.getElementById("phone").Value;
    var corr = document.getElementById("email").Value;
    var msj = document.getElementById("message").Value;



    db.collection("usuarios").add({
        nombre: nom,
        telefono: tel,
        email: corr,
        mensaje: msj
    })
    .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });


  }
```

Comment: El atributo `Value` es solo con minúsculas

Comment: Muchas gracias.